# Remove #wpcf7-f2450-o1 with Contact form 7 redirect

Tags: redirect, forms, wp-redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a contact form, when the form submits I want to redirect to the page **http://example.com/thankyou?c=thisisavariable** . I can redirect, the problem is he redirects to **http://example.com/thankyou?c=thisisavariable#wpcf7-f2450-o1** .

As you can see he adds **#wpcf7-f2450-o1** at the end. But I don't want that. This is my code in my theme's **functions.php**:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'ip_wpcf7_mail_sent');
function ip_wpcf7_mail_sent($wpcf7)
{
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $path = $url['path'];
    $path = trim($path, "/");
    $path = explode("/", $path, 3);
    $path = $path[1];

    wp_redirect('http://example.com/thankyou' . '?c=' . $path);

    exit;
}
```

But how can I remove the **#wpc7-..** ?